Add TransactionSecurityPolicy through REST API
I'm trying to add a TransactionSecurity Policy through the REST API with the following body:
{
    "ApexPolicyId": "01p8Z00000CR5Qz",
    "DeveloperName": "SL_Api_Anomaly_Event",
    "EventName": "PermissionSetEventStore",
    "State": "Enabled",
    "Type": "CustomApexPolicy",
    "ActionConfig": "{\"userNotificationList\":[{\"recipientId\":\"0058Z000007UisXQzz\",\"emailNotification\":false,\"inAppNotification\":false}],\"blockAction\":false,\"endSessionAction\":false,\"freezeAction\":false,\"twoFaAction\":false}"
}

When I submit this to /services/data/v60.0/tooling/sobjects/TransactionSecurityPolicy, I am getting
message: You must provide a valid Metadata field for TransactionSecurityPolicy
errorCode: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING
fields
What could be wrong?  Can I do this directly over the REST API?

When creating TSP from rest API. Your ActionConfig param should be passed as a textArea as per documentation.
I tried with this.
{
    "ApexPolicyId": "01pal00000ILKJ7AAP",
    "DeveloperName": "SL_Api_Anomaly_Event",
    "EventName": "ApiAnomalyEventStore",
    "State": "Enabled",
    "Type": "CustomApexPolicy",
    "ActionConfig": "{\"userNotificationList\":[{\"recipientId\":\"005al000006ilKk\",\"emailNotification\":false,\"inAppNotification\":false}],\"blockAction\":false,\"endSessionAction\":false,\"freezeAction\":false,\"twoFaAction\":false}"
}

and it works fine.


Other than adding the endSessionAction parameter, I can't tell what's different about your structure than mine.  Not sure where the TextArea thing comes into it.

The request body which you shared, in that ActionConfig this param seems to be a JSON object. But ActionConfig needs to be passed as textArea / or simple string as shown above. I have posted a link to documentation too for your reference.

I updated my question code to use the code sample format (so it didn't strip out the slashes).  What is different about yours vs mine?  What specifically makes yours a TextArea format?  Thank you for your help!

my assumption is that you are using a System Admin user to insert this, right?

yes, that's correct.
